# Without using jUnit running the repository method through service layer from main class

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i want to run sevice layer methods which uses repository method of spring data.In my service layer main class without using junit i want to test the service layer method for successfully execution but i am not able to give proper mapping for that  in xml file can u please check the xml file and tell me the mistake, the following error is coming while running the existing confifuration

```
    21 Mar, 2013 11:44:23 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2be9cb75: startup date [Thu Mar 21 11:44:23 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
21 Mar, 2013 11:44:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
21 Mar, 2013 11:44:24 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
21 Mar, 2013 11:44:24 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'datasource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
21 Mar, 2013 11:44:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@49bdc9d8: defining beans [datasource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,departmentService]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:733)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.nousinfo.test.Testjava.main(Testjava.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:250)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 25 more
```

This is my service layer

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {
    @Autowired
    DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean createDepartment(DepartmentBO departmentBO) {
        boolean isCreate = false;
        Department department = departmentRepository
                .save(convertDepartmentBO2Department(departmentBO));
        if (department != null) {
            isCreate = true;
        }
        return isCreate;
    }
```

this is how i m trying to run with main class

```
 ApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
         DepartmentServiceImpl departmentService = (DepartmentServiceImpl)applicationContext .getBean("departmentService");

         DepartmentBO departmentBO = new DepartmentBO();
         departmentBO.setDepartmentId("A1");
         departmentBO.setDepartmentName("ankur");
         departmentBO.setDepartmentLocation("nigeria");
         System.out.println(departmentService.createDepartment(departmentBO));
```

this is application-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">

    <!-- Database -->
    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.30:3306/employee" />
        <property name="username" value="hr" />
        <property name="password" value="hr123" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EmployeeSpringdata" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Jpa Repositories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.nousinfo.tutorial.repository"></jpa:repositories>
    <bean id="departmentService"
        class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.repository.service.impl.DepartmentServiceImpl">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

this is persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EmployeeSpringdata"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.Department</class>
        <class>com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.Employee</class>
        <class>com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeProject</class>
        <class>com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeProjectPK</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.30:3306/employee" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hr" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="hr123" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
            <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty clear about the reason: you defined which persistence provider to use. The easiest way is to configure a `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` bean as `jpaVendorAdapter` on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.